# How to make local touch event handler for windows phone page?

Tags: silverlight, event-handling, windows-phone-7, touch

I have several pages in my windows phone/silverlight project in a constructor of one of the pages added touch event handler like this:

```
Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
```

The problem is that it works for all the pages in my project, but I need to limit it just to one page. How can I do that?

How to make local touch event handler for windows phone page?

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
```

when the page is activated, not constructed.  Call

```
Touch.FrameReported -= Touch_FrameReported;
```

when the page is deactivated.